# Custom react hook causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, react-hooks

I have a custom fetch hook:

```
export const useFetch = (url: string) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<any>(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState<any>(null);

  const fetchList = (url: string) => {
    return API.get(AMPLIFY_ENPOINTS.default, url, { response: true });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFunc = async () => {
      try {
        const fetchResponse = await fetchList(url);
        setResponse(fetchResponse.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    };
    fetchFunc();
  }, [url]);

  return { response, error };
};
```

This I then use in a component:

```
const fetchOrders = useFetch(apiUrl);
useEffect(() => {
  const { response, error } = fetchOrders;
  if (error) setError(error);
  if (response) {...}
}, [fetchOrders]);
```

And this causes an infinite loop, how should I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fetchOrder reference keeps changes on each re-render since you are returning a newly created object each time and hence it triggers an infinite loop when you call `setError` within your useEffect.

Instead of adding `fetchOrders` as a dependency, add `response` and `error` separately

```
const { response, error } = useFetch(apiUrl);
useEffect(() => {
  if (error) setError(error);
  if (response) {...}
}, [response, error]);
```

Comment: Minor comment but might confuse some people: The first line of your useEffect doesn't make sense anymore, does it? To my understanding, you already destructure the useFetch response into response and error in the very first line of code and the variable fetchOrders is never initialized

Answer (score 0):

It is this line that is responsible for this

```
return { response, error };
```

And of course his partner in crime is this `[fetchOrders]` dependency array in the second useEffect.

The first line returns a new object and thus fetchOrders is always a new value.

After thinking about your code, I came up to conclude that you probably don't need the second useEffect at all (I think).

```
// the useFetch only re-fetches when url changes
const { response, error } = useFetch(url);

// use response directly, you don't need to re-set the error nor the response in your component.
```

But if you were to do a side effect with response, you can consider upgrading your useFetch hook to accept a callback parameter and useEffect with a response dependency.

Answer (score 0):

In your component, try wrapping the input in `useMemo`.

```
const url = useMemo(() => apiUrl, [])
const fetchOrders = useFetch(url);
useEffect(() => {
  const { response, error } = fetchOrders;
  if (error) setError(error);
  if (response) {...}
}, [fetchOrders]);
```

Otherwise, `apiUrl` is a local variable and gets recreated every time the functional component runs, causing the infinite loop.